# How do I call SalesForce SOAP methods via a stand alone SOAP client

Tags: web-services, soap, salesforce, soapui, soap-client

I can make calls to SalesForce using the steps [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector). However, I get error  when I try to make call using a stand alone web client [like this one](http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/). The  error is below. The user name and (password+token) supplied to login() is valid.

I am not sure why am I not able to call SOAP method from standalone SOAP client. I believe I should be able to. Do I have to always use [Force-wsc](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector) to connect to SalesForce?

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <login xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
      <username>MY_USERNAME</username>
      <password>PASSWORD+TOKEN</password>
    </login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response

```
ResponseCode: 500 (Server Error)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 03 Apr 2015 16:25:47 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie:BrowserId=KUXkegaIQ_aJnfVrQEeC-A;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Tue, 02-Jun-2015 16:25:47 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>INVALID_LOGIN</faultcode>
      <faultstring>INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <sf:LoginFault xsi:type="sf:LoginFault">
          <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_LOGIN</sf:exceptionCode>
          <sf:exceptionMessage>Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</sf:exceptionMessage>
        </sf:LoginFault>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Error on console:

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at SforceService.login(String username, String password)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at WebServiceStudio.MainForm.InvokeWebMethod()
```

Client screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The connector is using session header not username and password so you may generate SF session and input the header in standalone client settings.
Look at line 105 here https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sforce/ws/transport/SoapConnection.java

```
                SessionRenewer.SessionRenewalHeader sessionHeader = config.getSessionRenewer().renewSession(config);
                if (sessionHeader != null) {
                    addHeader(sessionHeader.name, sessionHeader.headerElement);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is perhaps you are sending the call to the wrong url?  Is it a test or production org?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml request is fine. Just check the endpoint (if you are using production wsdl, use production credentials, and the same for sandbox - or just change the endpoint for the service - ). If you are behind a proxy, I'd suggest to review your  .Net webservice studio settings to set the proxy settings there.

Hope this helps